# MS Excel macro runs different from VB Script?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have a VB Script file that I open using a task in Windows Task Scheduler each morning. The script opens MS Excel and then runs a macro stored in a workbook. The problem is that the macro runs differently if I use the VB Script file to kick off the macro versus when i run it myself from the workbook. Specifically, I find that "Refresh All" doesn't actually refresh all data connections when I run the macro starting from the VB Script file. It works fine if I run the macro from the workbook itself. I'm thinking that I am missing something in this VB Script to ensure MS Excel opens correctly and makes "refresh all" work properly. Anything plainly wrong with this VB Script?

```
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")

ObjExcel.Application.Visible = True

Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("K:\Analytic Reporting\11.Projects\TonyAdHoc\Autorefresher\DashboardAutorefresher.xlsm")

objExcel.Application.Run "DashboardAutorefresher.xlsm!Main"

ObjWB.Close True
ObjExcel.Quit
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are trying to do a refresh to pull data from a database, but you are not seeing any new data from this script when you manually open the Excel file after the script runs.

You will need to save the Excel file after making modifications.

```
ObjExcel.Save
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually seeing the modifications on one of the datasets (the main one when you open the file) but not on the rest. That's what is odd. It's as if it only sees one of the data connections

Comment: That might be something in the code you are calling.  Do you have the code for Main that you can share?.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone still caring about this, what I've found is that for connections to a database table, if the property "Enable Background Refresh" is selected, then the vba command in RefreshAll in the marco doesn't work.  So I add a little loop to disable that property for all the connections just to make sure before I call RefreshAll.  That fixed it for me.

```
           ' -- make sure enable background refresh is not checked else RefreshAll doesn't work
            Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
            For Each cn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
                cn.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
            Next cn
            
            ' -- then ok to refresh all
            ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Comment: Apart from being a [global solution to a local problem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081211-00/?p=19873), this code a) is based on a false premise (`BackgroundQuery` does not prevent the connection from working on `RefreshAll`; [`RefreshWithRefreshAll`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookconnection.refreshwithrefreshall) does, which is very easy to demonstrate), and b) incorrectly assumes that all connections use `OLEDBConnection` (as opposed to `DataFeedConnection`, `ModelConnection`, `ODBCConnection`, `TextConnection`, or `WorksheetDataConnection`).